# Rcpp and CULA: segmentation fault

Tags: r, cuda, rcpp, cula

I extracted the relevant bits from the *gputools R*-package to run a QR decomposition on my GPU using *Rcpp* by dynamically loading a shared library that links to *culatools*. Everything runs smoothly in the terminal and *R.app* on my Mac. The results agree with *R*'s *qr()* function, but the problem is that a segmentation fault occurs on exiting *R.app* (the error does not occur when using the terminal):

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x10911b050, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

I think I narrowed down the problem to the pointers 'a' and 'tau' in the .c file that links to *culatools*:

```
#include<cula.h>

void gpuQR(const int *m, const int *n, float *a, const int *lda, float *tau)
{
    culaInitialize();   
    culaSgeqrf(m[0], n[0], a, lda[0], tau);
    culaShutdown();
}
```

I compiled the .c file on my Mac using:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -gencode arch=compute_10,code=sm_10 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_12,code=sm_12 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -c -I. -I/usr/local/cula/include -m64 -Xcompiler -fPIC gpuQR.c -o gpuQR.o
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -gencode arch=compute_10,code=sm_10 -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11 -gencode arch=compute_12,code=sm_12 -gencode arch=compute_13,code=sm_13 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -shared -m64 -Xlinker -rpath,/usr/local/cula/lib64 -L/usr/local/cula/lib64 -lcula_core -lcula_lapack -lcublas -o gpuQR.so gpuQR.o
```

I wrote a .cpp file that uses *Rcpp* and dynamically loads the shared library gpuQR.so:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

typedef void (*func)(int*, int*, float*, int*, float*);

RcppExport SEXP gpuQR_Rcpp(SEXP x_, SEXP n_rows_, SEXP n_cols_)
{       
    vector<float> x = as<vector<float> >(x_);
    int n_rows = as<int>(n_rows_);
    int n_cols = as<int>(n_cols_);
    vector<float> scale(n_cols);

    void* lib_handle = dlopen("path/gpuQR.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!lib_handle) 
    { 
        Rcout << dlerror() << endl; 
    } else {
        func gpuQR = (func) dlsym(lib_handle, "gpuQR");  
        gpuQR(&n_rows, &n_cols, &(x[0]), &n_rows, &(scale[0]));
    }

    dlclose(lib_handle);

    for(int ii = 1; ii < n_rows; ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < n_cols; jj++)
        {
            if(ii > jj) { y[ii + jj * n_rows] *= scale[jj]; }
        }
    }

    return wrap(x);
}
```

I compiled the .cpp file in *R* using:

```
library(Rcpp)  
PKG_LIBS <- sprintf('%s $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)', Rcpp:::RcppLdFlags()) 
PKG_CPPFLAGS <- sprintf('%s', Rcpp:::RcppCxxFlags())  
Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS = PKG_LIBS , PKG_CPPFLAGS = PKG_CPPFLAGS) 
R <- file.path(R.home(component = 'bin'), 'R') 
file <- 'path/gpuQR_Rcpp.cpp'
cmd <- sprintf('%s CMD SHLIB %s', R, paste(file, collapse = ' '))
system(cmd)
```

and ran an example:

```
dyn.load('path/gpuQR_Rcpp.so')

set.seed(100)
A <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)
n_row <- nrow(A)
n_col <- ncol(A)

res <- .Call('gpuQR_Rcpp', c(A), n_row, n_col)
matrix(res, n_row, n_col)

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.5250958 -0.8666927  0.8594266
[2,] -0.2504899 -0.3878644 -0.1277837
[3,]  0.1502908  0.4742033 -0.8804248

qr(A)$qr

          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.5250957 -0.8666925  0.8594266
[2,] -0.2504899 -0.3878643 -0.1277838
[3,]  0.1502909  0.4742033 -0.8804247
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix the segmentation fault?

Comment: Why are you using nvcc to compile your code? If it is plain C code, you can (and probably should) use the host C compiler. nvcc uses a C++ host compilation route by default. That may not be what you want.

Comment: I just used what the *gputools R* package uses. Actually, *Nvidia* [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc) says the following about this: "... nvcc mimics the behavior of the GNU compiler gcc: it accepts a range of conventional compiler options, such as for defining macros and include/library paths, and for steering the compilation process. All non-CUDA compilation steps are forwarded to a general purpose C compiler that is supported by nvcc, ..."

Comment: Yes, I fully understand that. But be aware that the "general purpose compiler" is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. So you C code gets compiled with a C++ compiler. Most of the time it doesn't matter but sometimes it does. This might well be one of those times....

Comment: I compiled it using the gcc compiler: `gcc -c -I/usr/local/cula/include gpuQR.c` and
`gcc -shared -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cula/lib64 -L/usr/local/cula/lib64 -lcula_lapack -o gpuQR.so gpuQR.o` but the segmentation fault persists.

Comment: I removed the line `dlclose(lib_handle)` and the segmentation fault stops occurring. I think that this is the answer to the problem!

Comment: Please post what you did to fix it as an answer (rather than editing your question.  It's ok to answer your own question in cases like these).  Then I will upvote your answer.

Comment: Alright! I was not sure if this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by deleting

```
dlclose(lib_handle);
```

from .cpp file. This yields the following:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

typedef void (*func)(int*, int*, float*, int*, float*);

RcppExport SEXP gpuQR_Rcpp(SEXP x_, SEXP n_rows_, SEXP n_cols_)
{       
    vector<float> x = as<vector<float> >(x_);
    int n_rows = as<int>(n_rows_);
    int n_cols = as<int>(n_cols_);
    vector<float> scale(n_cols);

    void* lib_handle = dlopen("path/gpuQR.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!lib_handle) 
    { 
        Rcout << dlerror() << endl; 
    } else {
        func gpuQR = (func) dlsym(lib_handle, "gpuQR");  
        gpuQR(&n_rows, &n_cols, &(x[0]), &n_rows, &(scale[0]));
    }

    for(int ii = 1; ii < n_rows; ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < n_cols; jj++)
        {
            if(ii > jj) { x[ii + jj * n_rows] *= scale[jj]; }
        }
    }

    return wrap(x);
}
```

The .cpp file can be compiled in *R* using:

```
library(Rcpp)  
PKG_LIBS <- sprintf('%s $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)', Rcpp:::RcppLdFlags()) 
PKG_CPPFLAGS <- sprintf('%s', Rcpp:::RcppCxxFlags())  
Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS = PKG_LIBS , PKG_CPPFLAGS = PKG_CPPFLAGS) 
R <- file.path(R.home(component = 'bin'), 'R') 
file <- 'path/gpuQR_Rcpp.cpp'
cmd <- sprintf('%s CMD SHLIB %s', R, paste(file, collapse = ' '))
system(cmd)
```

The actual .c file linking to *culatools* is:

```
#include<cula.h>

void gpuQR(const int *m, const int *n, float *a, const int *lda, float *tau)
{
    culaInitialize();   
    culaSgeqrf(m[0], n[0], a, lda[0], tau);
    culaShutdown();
}
```

It can be compiled using:

```
gcc -c -I/usr/local/cula/include gpuQR.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cula/lib64 -L/usr/local/cula/lib64 -lcula_lapack -o gpuQR.so gpuQR.o
```

The QR decomposition can then be performed in *R* using:

```
dyn.load('path/gpuQR_Rcpp.so')

set.seed(100)

n_row <- 3
n_col <- 3
A <- matrix(rnorm(n_row * n_col), n_row, n_col)

res <- .Call('gpuQR_Rcpp', c(A), n_row, n_col)
matrix(res, n_row, n_col)

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.5250958 -0.8666927  0.8594266
[2,] -0.2504899 -0.3878644 -0.1277837
[3,]  0.1502908  0.4742033 -0.8804248

qr(A)$qr

          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.5250957 -0.8666925  0.8594266
[2,] -0.2504899 -0.3878643 -0.1277838
[3,]  0.1502909  0.4742033 -0.8804247
```

Here are the results from a benchmark using a NVIDIA GeForce 9400M GPU with 16 CUDA cores:

```
n_row <- 1000; n_col <- 1000
A <- matrix(rnorm(n_row * n_col), n_row, n_col)
B <- A; dim(B) <- NULL

res <- benchmark(.Call('gpuQR_Rcpp', B, n_row, n_col), qr(A), columns = c('test', 'replications', 'elapsed', 'relative'), order = 'relative')

                                  test replications elapsed relative
1 .Call("gpuQR_Rcpp", B, n_row, n_col)          100  38.037    1.000
2                                qr(A)          100 152.575    4.011
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no need to dynamically load a shared library linking to *culatools*. I thought about this initially, but I did not get the .cpp file using *Rcpp* compiled. Anyway, the new .cpp file is:

```
#include<Rcpp.h>
#include<cula.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

RcppExport SEXP gpuQR_Rcpp(SEXP x_, SEXP n_rows_, SEXP n_cols_)
{       
    vector<float> x = as<vector<float> >(x_);
    int n_rows = as<int>(n_rows_);
    int n_cols = as<int>(n_cols_);  
    vector<float> scale(n_cols);

    culaInitialize();   
    culaSgeqrf(n_rows, n_cols, &(x[0]), n_rows, &(scale[0]));
    culaShutdown();

    for(int ii = 1; ii < n_rows; ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < n_cols; jj++)
        {
            if(ii > jj) { x[ii + jj * n_rows] *= scale[jj]; }
        }
    }

    return wrap(x);
}
```

The .cpp file is compiled using:

```
library(Rcpp)  
PKG_LIBS <- sprintf('-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cula/lib64 -L/usr/local/cula/lib64 -lcula_lapack %s $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)', Rcpp:::RcppLdFlags()) 
PKG_CPPFLAGS <- sprintf('-I/usr/local/cula/include %s', Rcpp:::RcppCxxFlags())  
Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS = PKG_LIBS , PKG_CPPFLAGS = PKG_CPPFLAGS) 
R <- file.path(R.home(component = 'bin'), 'R') 
file <- 'path/gpuQR_inc.cpp'
cmd <- sprintf('%s CMD SHLIB %s', R, paste(file, collapse = ' '))
system(cmd)
```

where I set the appropriate path to *culatools*. The whole thing does not run faster, but there is no need any longer to compile the shared library linking to *culatools* and dynamically loading it.

I think that this is a nice alternative to the *gputools R*-package to extend *R* with *C++* and perform linear algebra operations on the GPU.