# MAGMA and Rcpp for linear algebra in R

Tags: r, cuda, rcpp, cula, magma

I was wondering if anybody has tried to use [*Rcpp*](http://www.rcpp.org) and [*MAGMA*](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/) to accelerate linear algebra operations in *R* by using the CPU and GPU? I tried [*culatools*](http://www.culatools.com/) last month and it worked with *Rcpp* ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925733/rcpp-and-cula-segmentation-fault/17974990#17974990)), but *culatools* is a commercial product that costs money to get access to all functions.

Answer (score 5):

It was pretty straightforward to use *Rcpp* and *MAGMA* after having tinkered around with *culatools*. Here is the .cpp file:

```
#include<Rcpp.h>
#include<magma.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

RcppExport SEXP gpuQR_magma(SEXP X_)
{    
    // Input
    NumericMatrix X(X_);

    // Initialize magma and cublas
    magma_init();
    cublasInit();

    // Declare variables 
    int info, lwork, n_rows = X.nrow(), n_cols = X.ncol(), min_mn = min(n_rows, n_cols);
    double tmp[1];
    NumericVector scale(min_mn);

    // Query workspace size
    magma_dgeqrf(n_rows, n_cols, &(X[0]), n_rows, &(scale[0]), &(work[0]), -1, &info); 
    lwork = work[0];
    NumericVector work(lwork);

    // Run QR decomposition
    magma_dgeqrf(n_rows, n_cols, &(X[0]), n_rows, &(scale[0]), &(work[0]), lwork, &info);

    // Scale factor result    
    for(int ii = 1; ii < n_rows; ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < n_cols; jj++)
        {
            if(ii > jj) { X[ii + jj * n_rows] *= scale[jj]; }
        }
    }

    // Shutdown magma and cublas    
    magma_finalize();
    cublasShutdown();

    // Output  
    return wrap(X);
}
```

The file can be compiled from R into a shared library using:

```
library(Rcpp)  
PKG_LIBS <- sprintf('-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/magma/lib -L/usr/local/magma/lib -lmagma /usr/local/magma/lib/libmagma.a -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64 %s', Rcpp:::RcppLdFlags()) 
PKG_CPPFLAGS <- sprintf('-DADD_ -DHAVE_CUBLAS -I/usr/local/magma/include -I/usr/local/cuda-5.5/include %s', Rcpp:::RcppCxxFlags())  
Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS = PKG_LIBS , PKG_CPPFLAGS = PKG_CPPFLAGS) 
R <- file.path(R.home(component = 'bin'), 'R') 
file <- '/path/gpuQR_magma.cpp'
cmd <- sprintf('%s CMD SHLIB %s', R, paste(file, collapse = ' '))
system(cmd)
```

The shared library can now be called in *R*. Comparing the results with with *R*'s *qr()* gives:

```
dyn.load('/path/gpuQR_magma.so')

set.seed(100)
n_row <- 3; n_col <- 3
A <- matrix(rnorm(n_row * n_col), n_row, n_col)

qr(A)$qr

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.5250957 -0.8666925  0.8594266
[2,] -0.2504899 -0.3878643 -0.1277838
[3,]  0.1502909  0.4742033 -0.8804247

.Call('gpuQR_magma', A)

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.5250957 -0.8666925  0.8594266
[2,] -0.2504899 -0.3878643 -0.1277838
[3,]  0.1502909  0.4742033 -0.8804247
```

Below are the results from a benchmark using a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675MX GPU with 960 CUDA cores and OpenBLAS:

```
n_row <- 3000; n_col <- 3000
A <- matrix(rnorm(n_row * n_col), n_row, n_col)
B <- A; dim(B) <- NULL

res <- benchmark(.Call('gpuQR_magma', A), .Call('gpuQR_cula', B, n_row, n_col), qr(A), columns = c('test', 'replications', 'elapsed', 'relative'), order = 'relative')

                                   test replications elapsed relative
2  .Call("gpuQR_cula", B, n_row, n_col)          100  18.704    1.000
1               .Call("gpuQR_magma", A)          100  70.461    3.767
3                                 qr(A)          100 985.411   52.685
```

Seems like as if *MAGMA* is a bit slower compared to *culatools* (in this example). However, *MAGMA* comes with out-of-memory implementations and that is something I value a lot given only 1Gb of GPU memory.

Comment: The Rcpp authors encourage people with nice example like yours to post on http://gallery.rcpp.org/ to share nice examples like yours. From my point of vue your stuff deserve a spot there... Let's see what they think

Comment: There are existing CRAN packages like WideLm which use Rcpp to get from R to the C-based API of CUDA; one could easily do the same for Magma.

Comment: There is actually the [magma *R*-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magma/index.html). It does not use *Rcpp* though. I posted my code for later references. Documentation for *MAGMA* is really thin and even thinner when it comes to using it with *Rcpp*.

Comment: Doh. Should have remembered the CRAN package magma.

Comment: Yes, I took that package as a starting point for my code. Does it make sense to submit a *Rcpp/MAGMA* example to the *Rcpp* gallery?

Comment: You would probably need to package it a bit more. It would need to run on the box converting the Rmd (or cpp) file for the post. Which needs to have Magma installed...

Comment: I have it as a R package now with configure and makefile. It looks for MAGMA on the box and runs with R CMD INSTALL ... What is next to get it in the gallery?

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'min(int&, int&)'

Comment: okay, used std::min... now my issue is "error: 'work' was not declared in this scope"